# Bash / Linux Permissions denied as SUDO

Tags: bash, docker, stdout, sudo, io-redirection

I am creating a small bash script to automate some simple tasks to handle my docker container. One of the commands I have is to clear the logs, but this doesnt work responding with "Permission denied".

The issue with this is I am using `sudo`.

```sh
if [ $CLEAR_OPT == true ]
then
  DOCKER_LOG_PATH=$(docker inspect $DOCKER_ID --format='{{.LogPath}}')
  sudo :> $DOCKER_LOG_PATH;
  exit 0
fi
```

This errors out.

However this following sequence of linux commands will not error out:

```
sudo -s
:> /var/lib/docker/containers/path/path-json.log
```

I tested without using `sudo -s` and it still didnt work in linux terminal.

Is there something I am missing? I thought when doing `sudo` it would run the command as root user?

Comment: How are you running your script?

Comment: simple bash
`chmod a+x script.sh`
`./script.sh --clear-logs`

Comment: try with `sudo bash script.sh --clear-logs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of your "working" example is executed in a new shell that already runs with root privileges, since `sudo -s` starts a new shell.

But the `:>` in your shell script will be executed by the shell and not by `sudo`, so it will run with the original (presumably lower) privileges.

The workaround is to pipe the output of something like `echo` to a command using sudo:  `echo | sudo tee "$DOCKER_LOG_PATH"`.

An even simpler and more explicit solution is to use a command that's explicitly built to truncate files: `sudo truncate -s0 "$DOCKER_LOG_PATH"`.